# BEATS AUDIO dv7 HP

Tags: sound

Who can help me with Linux audio problems generally (I tried ubuntu fedora Manjaro ect and I can not make it work on my laptop 4.1 hp dv7-6b77dx (has 2 speakers under the screen two more in the front and a subwoofer on the bottom next to the baterria)

versions of Linux with kernel 3.2 works sub and two speakers from but not those that are on the screen (HDA Analyzer Here I can make funionen all)

And With the Kernel 3.5 onwards operate 4 speakers but no subwoofer (Here I have not been able to work with the HDA ANALIZER)

---

Quien me puede ayudar con problemas de audio en Linux general ( He probado manjaro ubuntu fedora ect  y no puedo hacer que funcione el 4.1 de mi laptop hp dv7-6b77dx   ( tiene 2 bosinas bajo la pantalla 2 mas en la parte de enfrente y un subwoofer por la parte de abajo junto a la baterria )

las versiones de linux con kernel 3.2 funciona el sub y las dos bocinas de entre pero no las que estan bajo la pantalla  (Aqui con HDA  ANAlizer  puedo hacer que funionen todas)

Y Con el Kernel 3.5 en adelante funcionan las 4 bosinas pero no el subwoofer ( Aqui no lo he podido hacer funcionar con el HDA ANALIZER)

Answer (score 1):

see this link. This is how i was able to enable it http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/

Comment: I tried it on a HP dv7 envy .. it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the *model=hp-dv5* parm to the snd-hda-intel module.
There are a couple ways to do this. One easy way is to put the parm in:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add the line, or, replace an existing model if there is already a different on indicated:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5
```

Options put in this way will take effect on the next reboot.

FYI my HP DV7 is an [dv7-6c73ca](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=5218622&lc=en&cc=ca&dlc=en&lang=en&tmp_track_link=ot_we/prodlink/en_ca/5218622/loc:0&cc=ca).

# **dmidecode -t 1**

```
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
Product Name: HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC
...
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: A7G61UA#ABC
Family: 103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=PAV
```

# **lspci | grep -i audio**

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```